# Elasticsearch NEST client ReindexOnServer type problem

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Basically I want to rewrite this code:

```
  var values = "{\"source\":{\"index\": \"" + oldIndex.Index + "\",\"type\": \"" + MyType+ "\"},"
                                     + "\",\"size\": \"" + size + "\"},"
                                     + "\"dest\": {\"index\": \"" + tempIndex + "\",\"type\": \"_doc\"}}";

            var result = this.httpClient.PostAsync(ReIndexUrl, new StringContent(values, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
            var response = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

to NEST client:

```
  var response = elasticClient.ReindexOnServer(
                r => r
                    .Source(
                        s => s
                            .Index(sourceIndex)
                    )
                    .Destination(
                        d => d
                            .Index(targetIndex)
                    ).Refresh(false).Size(maximumDocuments)
                    .WaitForCompletion()
            );
```

While reindexing docs from V6 to V7 using NEST version, I get errors because of duplicate types on the target:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Rejecting mapping update to [audit-trail-2020-04-temp] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, audittrailentry]
```

I cannot find a way to workaround this issue using NEST since there is no way to exclude type?

Comment: Hello, did you ever find an answer to this? I have the almost the exact same problem and can't see anywhere that the NEST API allows the override of the destination index mapping type.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I dit not find a solution for this using NEST Client.
At the end I wrote my own extension:

```
  internal static long ReIndex(this IElasticClient elasticClient, ReindexModel reindexModel)
        {
            elasticClient.DisableRefreshing(reindexModel.SourceIndex);

            var result = HttpClient.PostAsync(ReIndexUrl, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reindexModel.Value), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
            var response = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var responseObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReindexResponse>(response);
            return responseObj.Total;
        }

 internal class ReindexModel
    {     

        public ReindexModel(string sourceIndex, string targetIndex, string docType, int maxBulkSize)
        {
            this.SourceIndex = sourceIndex;
            this.TargetIndex = targetIndex;
            this.DocType = docType;           

            this.Value = new { source = new { index = this.SourceIndex, type = this.DocType, size = maxBulkSize }, dest = new { index = this.TargetIndex, type = "_doc" } };
        }

        public object Value { get; }

        public string SourceIndex { get; }

        public string TargetIndex { get; }

        private string DocType { get; }
    }

 internal class ReindexResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public long Total { get; set; }
    }
```